# Linq query taking too long

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I wonder if someone can help me with this.  I have a LINQ query - no problems with it, but it takes far too long to return data

```
var result = Context.paf_wgs84.Where(c => c.Postcode.Contains(postcode)).Take(15);
```

Very simple, the idea as the user is typing, using AJAX, it returns a set of 15 possible matches.

The problem is, there are 1.6 million records

Running the following code in management studio takes around 3 seconds

```
SELECT   code
FROM     paf_wgs84
WHERE    (code LIKE '%EC1%')
```

where as running the following code takes less than a second

```
SELECT   TOP 15  code
FROM     paf_wgs84
WHERE    (code LIKE '%EC1%')
```

Is there a way of doing something similar in LINQ without using `.take()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "something similar ... without using .Take()"? Are you asking if you can perform a TOP 15 query without using .Take()?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use '.take()'?

Comment: Can you post the SQL Query that is being created and sent?

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: He's asking how he can make LINQ use the fast SQL (= "...TOP 15...") rather than the slow SQL (= whatever LINQ is doing right now). Apparently, LINQ is not using TOP 15 currently, *even though* Take(15) is used.

Comment: @Matt, have you tried putting that Linq query into LinqPad and seeing what query is being generated. As far as I know, when you use Take you will get a Top within your actually sql statement.

Comment: What is the type of "Context.paf_wgs84"?

Comment: I hope there's an index on `code` too :)

Comment: Linqpad ran top(15) and ran in the time I would expect - use there is an index on code.  I have just added an auto incrementing ID and set this to the primary key - made no difference if I am honest.  There is no way my application is using this same way to execute the sql as it is taking the same time with the normal select.  May have to try efprof

Comment: @Matt, you could try pre-compiled queries, but use EFProf, it should tell you whats doing what. Also the queries could run faster on Management studio becuase after the first run they get cached.

Comment: @Matt you don't happen to have an 'OrderBy' in your ef-query? That is a common way to kill performance of top-queries.

Comment: I have changed the statement to var result = Context.paf_wgs84.Where(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith(postcode)).Take(10).Select(c => c.Postcode).ToArray(); I think the foreach look to add to a string array was taking the performance away.  Thanks for everyones help tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. This will only return one column.

```
var result = Context.paf_wgs84.Where(c => c.Postcode.Contains(postcode)).Select(x=>new {x.Postcode}).Take(15);
```

The generated Sql statement will look like this.

```
/*
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '%s%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (15) [t0].[code]
FROM [paf_wgs84] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[code] LIKE @p0
*/
```

Comment: Indeed it does - problem is, that query takes less than a second to complete but takes 4 seconds to return as a list from the service.  Is the service slowing the process down?  Is it the asp.net ajax framework that is taking its sweet time?

Comment: @Matt, thats a bit of a different q. There are a few things I would suggest. First off are you using MVC, or just ASP.NET? You can then use MVC-Mini-Profiler to profile both the db queries and code, I would wrap each section of my code when I create the service, call the service and return the values, it can also be used within ur aspx page. This way you will get a fine grained result of exactly whats taking the most time. Once you have that info you should have a more direct path.

Answer (score 1):

the problem might be that your contains method in the statemnt it is not being mapped to a like statement in sql and  you  end up getting all the rows into sql and then doing a cotains search in your web tier instead of doing the same in your DB.

Use SqlMethods for the same.. somethig as follows:

```
SqlMethods.Like(c.Postcode, string.Format("%{0}%",postcode));
```

sometimes you can also use the string methods like: String.StartsWith or String.Ends with but in this you cant..

Also - LIKE clauses starting % are rarely a good idea - not least, it can't make effective use of any index. You might have better performance using "full text search"; but this isn't directly available via LINQ

hope that helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I altered the statement to

```
var result = Context.paf_wgs84.Where(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith(postcode)).Take(10).Select(c => c.Postcode).ToArray();
```

I used a foreach look to add to a string array - I think this is where I was losing time!

Thanks for everyones help though.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of these types of queries has been greatly improved in SQL Server 2012 using the new FETCH and OFFSET statements (although I haven't seen much benchmarking data to date...).

The trouble is EF doesnt utilize these new features yet.

A possible solution is to use SQL Server 2012 and write a sproc with FETCH/OFFSET and then target this using EF. Definitely not a short term solution but I wanted to point out this option.